# ASP.NET textbox UTF8

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, utf-8, textbox

I have a field of a table named SpeakerName. When I show it in a table, it shows the name correctly (eg. Efraín), but when passing it to a textbox, it shows this: Efraín
I think it is a UTF 8 and ASCII problem, how can I set the textbox to show the text correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can adjust with

```
var result = Server.HtmlEncode(yourText);
```

Answer (score 0):

I used HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(mytext) and it worked! 
I found this [Special (or foreign countries) characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11652928/special-or-foreign-countries-characters) very helpfull!
Thanks!